# How to run Nginx within a Docker container and set it up to reload its configuration every 6h?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm runnign NGINX in a Docker container, and I'm trying to find a way to start it up using `docker run` in a way that would order my NGINX to reload its configuration every 6h. I need this to be done, because I also use Certbot in another container, and I'd like the SSL certificate renewal process to be automated and applied, and for that I neen NGINX to reload its configuration on schedule.

At this point I use the folowing `docker run` sequence (more or less):

`docker run --restart=always -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443  \
  --name=nginx_RevPr nginx:latest                   \
  /bin/bash -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait ${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'`

The container created this way is running and working fine. The only problem I have is that I actually don't know if NGINX is really realoading its configuration. `docker logs` doesn't show anything.

I'd like to approach this problem in a twofold way:

1. How can I output to terminal / docker logs (`echo`?) the succcessful `nginx -s reload` modifying my `/bin/bash -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait ${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'`?
2. In case I miss something (I'm a beginner for both Docker and NGINX): do you see a way to achieve the results I'd like to get in a more reasonable way?

Please don't suggest Docker Compose.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Sorry, but why you want to do this with bash? I think the best solution is to use a time-based job scheduler software like `cron` or `at`.

Comment: There are some problems with cron jobs in a dockerized environment. If the cron job runs on the host OS, the system isn't platform agnostic. If the cron runs within the container,  it's considered an anti-pattern (containers will be harder to update). But it definitely can be done. I know that some folks run their dockerized NGINX and they pass args for a scheduled reload either in Docker Compose or ``docker run``. I'd like to know how (and a lot of resources over the Internet is misguiding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got it working.
I changed the CMD args line to:

`/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait ${!}; nginx -s reload && echo NGINX config reload for Certbot - OK; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'`

My main mistake was to enter the CMD using `/bin/bash`, where I should do `/bin/sh`. And the following `nginx -s reload && echo NGINX config reload for Certbot - OK` solved the problem with notyfying `docker logs` about config reload.